# Error: $injector:modulerr Module Error - chart.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, chart.js

Trying to integrate `chart.js` with `AngularJS`but this error is showing:

`Error: $injector:modulerr Module Error`.
`Failed to instantiate module chart.js`

I know the is error is to do with where the link is declared in your header, but I have followed instructions from [Angular Chart](http://jtblin.github.io/angular-chart.js/#getting_started) but to no avail. Any idea why this error is being thrown?

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.4.0/Chart.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-charts/0.2.7/angular-charts.min.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/app.js"></script>
```

---

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute', 'angularMoment', 'ui.router', 'chart.js']);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Name of the chart module is `angularCharts`. so inject it instead of the `chart.js`

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute', 'angularMoment', 'ui.router', 'angularCharts']);
```

Comment: Well.... that was it. How come on the website it tells you to add `chart.js` as a dependency?

Comment: actually not sure why is that. i just look up the module and saw the name :D

Comment: Pffft, I been typing it in the last hour or so and they all say inject `chart.js`. God knows. Thanks for the help, I'll accept your answer asap